# Limit the x-axis values of a barplot in r

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2

I have a raster that includes the 120 million pixel values 0,1,10,11.
I generate a percentage raster. But I want the x-axis to show only the pixel values.

```
a = as.data.frame(diff_raster[[5]])

ggplot(a, aes(x = SENTINEL2A_20210304)) +
 geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count" ,        
          color=c("darkred", "green","turquoise2","purple"),
          width=1) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1,10,11))+
 scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
 geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
 labs(title="SENTINEL2A_20210304_T34HBJ_South_Africa", x="pixels", y="pixel frequencies", fill ="class")+
 theme_minimal(base_size=10)
```

This is what I get when I run the code above.
I cannot share my data somehow it starts a process as if it will take forever

[image]

I don't want the blank between numbers like in this plot

Comment: Note this isn't really a GIS question once you've got the values out into a data frame - you'd probably get better response on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by plotting the data as a *factor* but that also means you need to change some values to be `..count../sum(..count..)`.

First if you can't give us your data, you can always try and make something similar that works the same way. For example I think this is equivalent:

```
a = data.frame(
    SENTINEL2A_20210304 = sample(c(0,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,11,11),1000,TRUE)
)
```

Then here's the `ggplot` stuff with the data converted to a factor:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=factor(SENTINEL2A_20210304))) +
    geom_bar(
        aes(
            y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),
            fill = factor(..x..)
            ),
        stat="count") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=22)) +
    geom_text(aes(
        label = scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..)),
        y= ..count../sum(..count..) ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)
```

[image]

You might want to adjust colours, labels, and text sizes etc to your exact preference (I had to set text size to 22 points because of my hi-res screen).